# How to format multi-line cell of numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, multiline, number-formatting

Given an Excel cell with multiple lines (text wrapping).

E.g.

```
5501.700
640.8690
1081.45600
41.100
```

I want to format all the numbers (**in this single cell**) to have 2 decimal places and thousand separators. What are my options to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way is with a macro; read value, split each line, format, join.

ALT+F11, insert -> module and add;

```
Public Function FORMATLINES(cell As Range) As String
Dim data() As String, i As Long
data = Split(cell.Text, vbLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(data)
    If IsNumeric(data(i)) Then data(i) = FormatNumber(data(i), 2, vbTrue, vbFalse, vbTrue)
Next
FORMATLINES = Join(data, vbLf)
End Function
```

For

```
=FORMATLINES(A1)
```

Gives me;

```
5,501.70
640.87
1,081.46
41.10
```

Comment: Sounds good, for the new cell I should've also set the _Alignment_ option for _Text Wrapping_ to be true.